# Performance difference between system call vs function call

Tags: performance, x86, kernel, system-calls

I quite often listen to driver developers saying its good to avoid kernel mode switches as much as possible. I couldn't understand the precise reason. To start with my understanding is -

1. System calls are software interrupts. On x86 they are triggered by using instruction sysenter. Which actually looks like a branch instruction which takes the target from a machine specific register.
2. System calls don't really have to change the address space or process context.
3. Though, they do save registers on process stack and and change stack pointer to kernel stack.

Among these operations syscall pretty much works like a normal function call. Though the sysenter could behave like a mis-predicted branch which could lead to ROB flush in processor pipeline. Even that is not really bad, its just like any other mis-predicted branch.

I heard a few people answering on Stack Overflow:

1. You never know how long syscall takes - [me] yeah, but thats case with any function. Amount of time it takes depends on the function
2. It is often scheduling spot. - [me] process can get rescheduled, even if it is running all the time in user mode. ex, `while(1);` doesnt guarantee a no-context switch.

Where is the actual syscall cost coming from?

Comment: Perf on modern processors is dominated by how well a program uses the caches.  Nothing worse than a ring transition, every cache is junk.  Reloading the data, instruction and TLB caches from RAM takes a lot of time, especially when the data is swapped out.

Comment: I am not quite sure, what you mean here. My understanding is caches never have to be flushed on ring transition as address space is still same. Caches and TLB need to be flushed only on process contest switch. Even that doesnt need to happen if processor can mark TLB entries with some address space (or process) identifiers.

Answer (score 4):

You don't indicate what OS you are asking about. Let me attempt an answer anyway.

The CPU instructions `syscall` and `sysenter` should not be confused with the concept of a [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) and its representation in the respective OSs.

The best explanation for the difference in the overhead incurred by each respective instruction is given by reading through the **Operation** sections of the *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Developer's Manual* [volume 2A](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2a-manual.html) (for `int`, see page 3-392) and [volume 2B](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2b-manual.html) (for `sysenter` see page 4-463). Also don't forget to glance at `iretd` and `sysexit` while at it.

A casual counting of the pseudo-code for the operations yields:

- 408 lines for `int`
- 55 lines for `sysenter`

**Note:** Although the existing answer is right in that `sysenter` and `syscall` are not interrupts or in any way related to interrupts, *older kernels in the Linux and the Windows world **used interrupts to implement their system call mechanism***. On Linux this used to be `int 0x80` and on Windows `int 0x2E`. And consequently on those kernel versions the IDT had to be primed to provide an interrupt handler for the respective interrupt. On newer systems, that's true, the `sysenter` and `syscall` instructions have completely replaced the old ways. With `sysenter` it's the MSR (machine specific register) `0x176` which gets primed with the address of the handler for `sysenter` (see the reading material linked below).

---

### On Windows ...

A system call on Windows, just like on Linux, results in the switch to kernel mode. The scheduler of NT doesn't provide any guarantees about the time a thread is granted. Also it yanks away time from threads and can even end up starving threads. In general one can say that user mode code can be preempted by kernel mode code (with very few very specific exceptions to which you'll certainly get in the "advanced driver writing class"). This makes perfect sense if we only look at one example. User mode code can be swapped out - or, for that matter, the data it's trying to access. Now the CPU doesn't have the slightest clue how to access pages in the swap/paging file, so an intermediate step is required. And that's also why kernel mode code must be able to preempt user mode code. It is also the reason for one of the most prolific bug-check codes seen on Windows and mostly caused by third-party drivers: `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`. It means that a driver accessed paged memory when it wasn't possible to preempt the code touching that memory.

---

### Further reading

1. [SYSENTER and SYSEXIT in Windows](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/cpu/sep.htm) by Geoff Chappell (always worth a read in my experience!)
2. [Sysenter Based System Call Mechanism in Linux 2.6](http://articles.manugarg.com/systemcallinlinux2_6.html)
3. Windows NT platform specific discussion: [How Do Windows NT System Calls REALLY Work?](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/devicedriverdevelopment/article.php/c8035/How-Do-Windows-NT-System-Calls-REALLY-Work.htm)
4. Windows NT platform specific discussion: [System Call Optimization with the SYSENTER Instruction](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/system/article.php/c8223/System-Call-Optimization-with-the-SYSENTER-Instruction.htm)
5. Windows Internals, 5th ed., by Russinovich et. al. - pages 125 through 132.
6. [ReactOS implementation of `KiFastSystemCall`](https://code.google.com/p/reactos-mirror/source/browse/branches/ros-amd64-bringup/reactos/dll/ntdll/dispatch/i386/dispatch.S)

Answer (score 2):

`SYSENTER`/`SYSCALL` **is not** a software interrupt; whole point of those instructions is to avoid overhead caused by issuing IRQ and calling interrupt handler.

Saving registers on stack costs time, this is one place where the syscall cost comes from.

Another place comes from the kernel mode switch itself. It involves changing segment registers  - CS, DS, ES, FS, GS, they all have to be changed (it's less costly on x86-64, as segmentation is mostly unused, but you still need to essentially make far jump to kernel code) and also changes CPU ring of execution.

To conclude: function call is (on modern systems, where segmentation is not used) near call, while syscall involves far call and ring switch.

Comment: I understand bit better now. So, in x86 the main cost behind system call is saving registers!! And the difference is near call and far call?

Comment: @BhaskarMuppana, process of saving registers isn't as big as cost of switching processor ring and segment registers.